# How to access a selector on AJAX Complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I make an Ajax Request that adds content to the page with HTML from the back-end, and then I make another Ajax Request that modifies that dynamically added HTML.

```
    $("#list-customers-button").click(function () {
        var selectedAcquirer = $("#acquirer-select").val();
        if (selectedAcquirer === "adyen") {
            if (listed) {
                listed = false;
                $("#customer-list-area").hide().html('').fadeIn(fadeTime);
            } else {
                listed = true;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/adyen_list_customers",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $("#list-progress").show();
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                        $("#customer-list-area").hide().html(data["response_html"]).fadeIn(fadeTime).promise().done(function () {
                            $(".collapsible").collapsible();
                            resetDatepicker();

                        });

                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        $(document).on("change", "#file-download-datepicker", function () {
                            $("#file-download-progress").hide();
                            $("#file-download-date").val(selectedDate);
                            fileDownloadData = $("#file-download-form").serialize();
                            displayMessage(fileDownloadData);
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "/adyen_update_file_list_by_date",
                                data: fileDownloadData,
                                beforeSend: function () {
                                    $("#file-download-progress").show();
                                },
                                success: function (response) {

                                },
                                complete: function (response) {
                                    $("#file-download-progress").hide();
                                    console.log(response.responseText);
                                    // Doesn't work. Selector should exist, but it doesn't.
                                    $("#merchant-file-list").html(response.responseText); 
                                },
                                error: function (response) {
                                    displayMessage(response["responseText"]);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        displayMessage(data);
                    },
                });
            }
        } else if (selectedAcquirer === "stone") {
            displayMessage("Adquirente indisponível no momento.");
        } else {
            displayMessage("É necessário selecionar uma adquirente.");
        }
    });
```

I get a perfect HTML response from the server, but selectors that were previously added with HTML also from the server (#file-download-progress, #merchant-file-list) are completely ignored. .html() doesn't work, nor anything, and I don't know how to use .on() to work around this because I just need to access that content. Since the ajax request is being made after the previous one is complete, they *should* be able to be accessed. They just don't exist nowhere in time.

Comment: Needlessly putting `$(document).on("change", "#file-download-datepicker"` inside complete callback. Since that is a delegated event listener it can be put in page load code. Will organize a bit better with less nesting of all that code

Comment: I was just paranoid delegating the event inside there, it doesn't work on load anyway. The point is that since I've dynamically added HTML content once, trying to modify that content with another Ajax Request seems impossible.

Comment: That delegation will work regardless of when that element is added to the dom.

Comment: Are you repeating that ID or any others?

Comment: But the delegation is for the event (The change event on the datepicker). The problem is with the *selector* that is dynamically added. It exists only after the first ajax request, and it doesn't exist for the second ajax request.

Comment: No, all the selectors that were added through ajax success/complete stop working afterwards, I can't add html to them.

Comment: Misunderstanding how delegation works then. The event is listened to on `document` which always exists and the handler only fires if the target matches the delegate selector

Comment: Suggest you do everything in the `success` and not use both `success` and `complete`

Comment: The delegation works fine, that event is triggered ok. I add that datepicker together with those selectors in a first ajax request (The response is HTML from the server). When change is triggered on that datepicker that was added, more HTML content should be added (Another ajax request). Then, the selectors stop working (On the second time). It's not about delegation exactly.

Comment: Have you tried logging the length of the selector to verify that the element is(not) being found?

Comment: @Taplar, both the length of the selector returns 1 and the response HTML comes ok from the server. Still, the html() doesn't work (No content is added). It makes no sense.

Comment: `console.log($('[id="merchant-file-list"]').length)` and verify it is only 1

Comment: `$('[id="merchant-file-list"]').length` returns 38, `$("#merchant-file-list").length` returns 1. response.responseText returns the correct HTML response from the server.

Comment: So there's your problem. You are repeating id's in a page when you should be using class instead. ID's must be unique by definition. Your code is probably working but will only insert the html in the very first matching id and you are looking for it somewhere else

Comment: I generate that on a loop on the server, that's why I did not see it. Can't believe it! I'll attach a number to that id on the server. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can use class and a traverse from the corresponding date element also. Incrementing ID's will make it even more complicated

Comment: That content needs to be specific, each of the 38 needs to have specific content when accessed. It is complicated, that's why I've made such a confusion. Thanks for helping me notice it.

Comment: Right but there is some relationship between the specific date field and the other elements...like same row or same indexing that can be used to query a matching class element